# How do i start multiple threads in a for loop?

Tags: java, multithreading

At first starting threads in a for loop was just creating one, and starting it, but in a for loop, I decided to print out the thread name, and thread id, but found that only the last thread created is the one used.

```
public static void runSnipe(int threadsC) {
        NameSnipe NS = new NameSnipe();
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[threadsC];
        NS.DropTome = System.currentTimeMillis() + 500;
        for (int i = 0; i < threadsC; i++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(NS);
            threads[i] = t;
            threads[i].setName(String.valueOf(i + 1));
            NS.ThreadName = String.valueOf(threads[i].getName());

            threads[i].start();
            System.out.println(NS.ThreadName + " || " + threads[i].getName());
        }
    }



public class NameSnipe implements Runnable {
    public long DropTome;
    public String ThreadName;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long unixTimern = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (unixTimern < DropTome) {
            unixTimern = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        System.out.println("Thread " + ThreadName + " done at " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

I believe it has something to do with the fact that I can not change the value of ThreadName in NameSnipe, but if that is the case, i would not know how to solve it.

Also, these are the results i get:

```
1 || 1
2 || 2
3 || 3
4 || 4
5 || 5
6 || 6
7 || 7
8 || 8
9 || 9
10 || 10
Thread 10 done at 1595079115141
Thread 10 done at 1595079115141
Thread 10 done at 1595079115141
Thread 10 done at 1595079115141
Thread 10 done at 1595079115141
Thread 10 done at 1595079115142
Thread 10 done at 1595079115143
Thread 10 done at 1595079115143
Thread 10 done at 1595079115143
Thread 10 done at 1595079115144

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: There are two things happening here 1.) you are changing the state of the same object over and over again 2) you have added 500 ms to NS.DropTome and are using that time in the run() which makes all the threads enter the run() but wait until the condition is passed. By that time the for loop is finished setting the value of your ThreadName to 10. Just change the NS.DropTome = System.currentTimeMillis() + 500; to NS.DropTome = System.currentTimeMillis() + 0; and see the difference for yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are sharing a single `NameSnipe` object between all your threads. And you keep modifying the name of it as you iterate. And when threads come to read the `ThreadName` value, it has been set to 10 in the last iteration of the for-loop.

One direct solution is to simply create a separate object for each thread:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runSnipe(10);
    }

    private static void runSnipe(int threadsC) {
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[threadsC];
        for (int i = 0; i < threadsC; i++)
        {
            NameSnipe NS = new NameSnipe(); // create a separete NameSnipe per thread
            NS.DropTome = System.currentTimeMillis() + 500;

            Thread t = new Thread(NS);
            threads[i] = t;
            threads[i].setName(String.valueOf(i + 1));
            NS.ThreadName = String.valueOf(threads[i].getName());

            threads[i].start();
            System.out.println(NS.ThreadName + " || " + threads[i].getName());
        }
    }

    private static class NameSnipe implements Runnable {
        long DropTome;
        String ThreadName;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            long unixTimern = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (unixTimern < DropTome) {
                unixTimern = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            System.out.println("Thread " + ThreadName + " done at " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 || 1
2 || 2
3 || 3
4 || 4
5 || 5
6 || 6
7 || 7
8 || 8
9 || 9
10 || 10
Thread 1 done at 1595079627569
Thread 2 done at 1595079627569
Thread 6 done at 1595079627570
Thread 8 done at 1595079627570
Thread 9 done at 1595079627570
Thread 7 done at 1595079627570
Thread 10 done at 1595079627570
Thread 3 done at 1595079627570
Thread 4 done at 1595079627570
Thread 5 done at 1595079627570
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the same Runnable instance is used for all the threads which have a state (`ThreadName` variable). Every time the loop is executed the `ThreadName` variable is changed to the iterator number (`i`) + 1. So for the final iteration, its value becomes 10. Now since the same instance of runnable is used for all the threads, all threads print the value 10 after execution. A better way could be to create multiple runnable objects to get multiple values. Something like this:

```
public static void runSnipe(int threadsC) {
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[threadsC];
    for (int i = 0; i < threadsC; i++)
    {
        NameSnipe NS = new NameSnipe();
        NS.DropTome = System.currentTimeMillis() + 500;
        Thread t = new Thread(NS);
        threads[i] = t;
        threads[i].setName(String.valueOf(i + 1));
        NS.ThreadName = String.valueOf(threads[i].getName());

        threads[i].start();
        System.out.println(NS.ThreadName + " || " + threads[i].getName());
    }
}
```